# Fantasy 80's movie quicksand scene where character leaves a medallion hanging

Tags: story-identification, movie

I need help finding a fantasy or adventure movie probably from the '80s (more likely) in which a character falls into quicksand and dies but just before being submerged he leaves a medallion hanging from a tree branch.

That´s pretty much all I can remember, I have the impression that he was being chased by men mounted on horses and the movie was cut for commercials after showing the hanging medallion.

Also not sure but the medallion probably had a red gem in it.

Comment: Could be *Krull*, the date is right and there was definitely a quicksand scene.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Did that scene involve a medallion though?